# reverse engineer an aws installation

Tags: amazon-web-services, automation, rds

Given an existing VPC with an RDS instance is there a tool that I can use to reverse engineer a script (e.g. an Ansible playbook) that will regenerate all of the objects in the VPC & RDS configuration (e.g. security groups, subnets, configuration, etc)?

Answer (score 1):

[CloudFormer attempts to do this](http://blogs.aws.amazon.com/application-management/post/Tx3GTYN785E71O/Building-AWS-CloudFormation-Templates-Using-CloudFormer). It isn't perfect, generally speaking it's important to be cloudformation-literate if you choose this option.

Otherwise, it's a great learning exercise (and stack planning exercise) to iteratively build your stack from scratch.